# Where is the copy template button in Template manager in J3.3.1 after update?

Tags: update, administration, template-manager

I am in the backend of a Joomla 3.3.1 site and I can't see the "Copy Template" button. Is it removed from the latest Joomla or what?

**Updating the question...**
I can't see the "Copy Template" button in 2 websites recently updated from 3.3.0 / 3.2.x.
I can see the button in a website recently updated from 2.5.x though, and of course the "Copy Template" button should exist in the template manager and not had been removed.
 
So what it remains to be answered from my initial question is the "or what?" part...

Anyone else faced the same, after updating from 3.x to latest 3.3.1?

Comment: Did you uninstall the core templates (Protostar, Beez, Hathor)? I have a site where I can reproduce this problem and discovering/installing those templates fixed it.

Comment: I do not have those templates installed in the first website, can't recall about the second one. Will check your suggestion Bakual and report back.

Comment: I think I found the bug. YOu also miss the "Rename File" button if you edit a file?
And you have uninstalled Hathor?
There is a funny check in https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_templates/views/template/view.html.php#L222 and some other places which likely is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Joomla.
Solution: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3858

Please test :-)

Comment: Can you please add a comment on the PullRequest if you tested the change?

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated

We haven't experienced this problem in Joomla 3.x after updates from previous versions (as shown in the update dev site below). However, in the past we have experienced situations where Joomla cache had to be deleted or the browsers cache had to be manually cleared after running the built-in Joomla Update mechanism, although we haven't experienced this recently.

---

*Previous answer*

In the `Template Manager` open the template you want to make a copy of and you will find in the top left a `Copy Template` button as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: Joomla 3.3 Template Manager: Customise Template]

Click on the `Copy Template` button and provide a name for the "new" template, you can use letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores (no spaces etc) for the name.
Somewhat oddly, if you want to delete a copy of a template (or any template for that matter) you must navigate to `Extension Manager: Manage` set the `Type` to `Template` and then select your copy and then click `Uninstall` as shown below:
[image: Joomla 3.3 Uninstall a template]

Comment: The problem is (as described in my question), that there is no "Copy Template" button. I checked this on two 3.3.1 websites, recently updated from other 3.x.

Comment: Actually your question was "Is it removed from the latest Joomla or what?" — these are screenshots from my 3.3.1 installation on my dev. computer which shows it wasn't removed.

Comment: Have you cleared the caches per my update, in the past we've seen odd things after using Joomla Update.

Comment: caches are cleared